# How to auto-convert HTML indentation from four spaces to two spaces?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, indentation

How do I auto-convert HTML indentation from four spaces to two spaces?

For now, I have to:

1. convert indentation to tab
2. set tab size to 2
3. convert indentation to space

file by file.

Is there any easy way to auto-convert the indentation when I edit/create a HTML file? Install a package or add some settings?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether there's a way to run a Sublime Text package (or macro) on multiple files, so this is not really a Sublime Text solution.

You could use [gulp-indent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-indent) and run your Gulp task using [this package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gulp). Here's an example configuration for `Gulpfile.js`:

```
var indent = require("gulp-indent");    

gulp.src("./src/*.html")
.pipe(indent({
    tabs: false,
    amount: 2
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a good way.But I realize should not use "all" in the question, just because I want sublime auto detect current edit/create file, if it is `html`, then convert the indent, other code still use space 4. Wouldn't need execute another command in this way.

Comment: Why not simply use an indentation package, e.g. [HTML-CSS-JS Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify)?